# Maintain text color in selected option

Tags: html, css

I have created a HTML form with 3 separate drop downs for  "Program", "Unit", "Location", I want the selected option text to maintain the text color when selected (defaults to black).

There 20+ programs, 100+units, 60+ locations. Program color matches corresponding Unit and Location colour.

This will allow form users to find selections easier and to proof there selections before submitting. (Do the colors match?)

```
<p>
    <label for="name">Program: </label>
    <select type="list" name="Program">
        <option style="color:#000000">Select One</option>
        <option style="color:#FF0000">Select One</option>
        <option style="color:#000099">Select One</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: This is not possible with pure CSS. You would expect that the selected `option` is shown but technically the text of the selected `option` is shown. To make this happen you need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery for this: see http://jsfiddle.net/n9bzwy8m/1/

Create a function that runs every time the select is changed and change the color based on the value of the new selection.

jQuery:

```
var select = $('#program');

select.change(function() {
    if (select.val() == "One") {
        select.css('color','#000000');
    }
    else if (select.val() == "Two") {
        select.css('color','#ff0000');      
    }
    else {
        select.css('color','#00ff00');
    }
});
```

HTML (I just added an id of `#program` to your `select` element):

```
<p>
    <label for="name">Program: </label>
    <select type="list" name="Program" id="program">
        <option style="color:#000000">One</option>
        <option style="color:#FF0000">Two</option>
        <option style="color:#000099">Three</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}
```

The above CSS removed default browser styling from the `select` element, which I think might be the problem you have with the color defaulting to black. You can then add your own styling to the `select` - `padding`, `border-radius`, `border`, `background` etc.